# Is there a better way to do this based on a HTMLmenu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

What I want is to load an `iframe` depending on which option is selected in a menu, this is just an example, it will have more options and I want to know if there's a way to simplify this or make it for a menu with N options

```
const menu = () =>{
    const personalInfo= document.getElementById('infoPers')
    const medicInfo= document.getElementById('infoMed')
    const frameInfoPer= document.getElementById('framePersonalInfo')
    const frameInfoMed = document.getElementById('frameMedicInfo')

    personalInfo.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        frameInfoPer.style.display = "block"
        frameInfoMed.style.display = "none"
    })
    medicInfo.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        frameInfoMed.style.display = "block"
        frameInfoPer.style.display = "none"
    })
}

window.onload = () =>{
    menu()
}
```

Comment: Why not loop around all the `id`s?

Comment: @gaganshera because I don't know how, I'm just learning with all of this

Comment: thanks for the idea I will search how to do that

Comment: I would suggest looking into html `class`es instead of `id`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using classes and data-attributes, I'm able to create a reusable menu function.

For each link in your menu, add the class of `load-iframe` and a data attribute for the target iframe. You can update the code so that the href of the menu link is used as the iframe src also, I didn't do that because I wasn't sure how your iframes are generated.

```js
const menu = () =>{
   
    const iframelinks = document.querySelectorAll(".load-iframe");
    const iframes = document.querySelectorAll(".iframe");
    
    iframelinks.forEach(function(el){
    
       el.addEventListener("click",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          
          iframes.forEach(function(iframe){
            iframe.style.display = "none";
          });
          
          document.querySelector(el.getAttribute("data-target")).style.display = "block";
       });
    });
}

window.onload = () =>{
    menu()
}
```

```css
.iframe{display:none;}
```

```html
<a class="load-iframe" data-target="#frameMedicInfo" href="#url">URL1</a>
<a class="load-iframe" data-target="#framePersonalInfo" href="#url2">URL2</a>

<div class="iframe" id="frameMedicInfo">FAKE IFRAME frameMedicInfo</div>
<div class="iframe" id="framePersonalInfo">FAKE IFRAME framePersonalInfo</div>
```